# Calculus Question from a contest

Tags: calculus

A triangle with vertices at (1003, 0), (1004, 3), and (1005, 1) in the xy-plane is revolved
all the way around the y-axis. Find the volume of the solid thus obtained.  I get a volume of $\frac{25\pi}{9}$  But the answer is supposed to be $5020\pi$.  Could someone let me know if I am wrong.

$$\int_{0}^{1} \pi (2y+1003-\frac{y}{3}-1003)^2 dy + \int_{1}^{3} \pi (\frac{(3-y)}{2}+1004-\frac{y}{3}-1003)^2 dy = \frac{25\pi}{9}$$

Edit

$$\int_{0}^{1} \pi \left((2y+1003)^2-(\frac{y}{3}-1003)^2\right) dy + \int_{1}^{3} \pi \left((\frac{(3-y)}{2}+1004)^2-(\frac{y}{3}-1003)^2\right) dy = 5020\pi$$

Comment: The appropriate thing to integrate has the form $\pi(R^2-r^2)$, not $\pi(R-r)^2$.

Comment: Oh!!. I got it?  Thank you very much!!.  It has been sometime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing the integral into 2 parts is a good approach, as the area of a horizontal cut of the solid does have 2 formulas when z is between 0 and 1 and between 1 and 3. However, the expressions inside the integrals for the areas of the cuts are incorrect.

Hint: each horizontal cut is in the shape of a ring composed of an outer circle and an inner circle. Try to calculate the area of the outer circle and subtract the area of the inner circle to retrieve the correct expression for the area of a cut (it seems to me like instead, you calculated the area of a circle with subtracted radii, which isn't correct).